# SharePoint deployment at two scopes(global & webURL) what is the difference between web-application and globally deployed?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

SharePoint server 2013 solutions,some solutions are deployed in Globally and some solutions are deployed in web application.

why this happening and what is the difference between globally deployed and web application deployed?please anyone clarify this.Thanks in advance.
what is the main difference of globally deployed and webapplication.

Answer (score 0):

**Web Site scoped Feature (Scope=”Web”)**

- Web Site Scoped feature can be activated at individual Web site level
- List Instances, Event Receivers, Custom Actions etc are the custom elements for Website scope features
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature “name FeatureFolderName “url http://sharepointserver/site/subsite
- Alternatively open site features page by site actions -> site settings -> modify all site settings ->site features and click activate

**Site Collection scoped Feature (Scope=”Site”)**

- Site Collection Scoped feature can be activated at the site collection level
- It can contains item that can apply to Site Collection as a whole like content types that are shared across the site collection, as well as items that can be activated per site for e.g. List Instances, Event Receivers, Custom Actions etc
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature “name FeatureFolderName “url http://sharepointserver/site/sitecollectionname
- Alternatively open site features page by site actions -> site settings -> modify all site settings ->site features and click activate

**Web Application scoped Feature (Scope=”WebApplication”)**

- Web Application Scoped feature can be activated at the Web application level
- It can contains item like administrative web application links, delegate control registrations, document forms registration etc
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature “name FeatureFolderName “url http://sharepointserver
- Alternatively open Manage Web Application Features from Central Administrator Central Administrator -> Application Management -> Manage Application Features and click activate

**Farm scoped Feature (Scope=”Farm”)**

- Farm Scoped feature can be activated at the Farm level
- It can contain number of element like application logic etc which can be applicable anywhere within deployment. It contacts links to /_layouts pages and files, /_admin pages etc
- It can be activated by STSADM command like ” stsadm “o installfeature “name FeatureFolderName
- Alternatively open Manage Farm Features from Central Administrator Central Administrator -> Operations -> Manage Application Features and click activate
- Farm scope feature will be activated automatically once it is installed on server

**References**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460318.aspx

http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/understanding-scope-of-sharepoint-features-%28wss-30moss-2007%29.aspx

Referenced from below URL:

http://www.pritambaldota.com/index.php/understanding-features-and-feature-scope-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I want to know the difference between globally deployed and weburl.
solution deployed in globally event-receivers some issues will came.
I want to know advantage and disadvantage of globally deployed and web application.please share any link for this.

Comment: The answer sure is in your text, but it is not clearly visible if you do not already know it. Can you please reword your answer to make it more clear what is causing the solution to be web-app or globally deployed?

Comment: I refered this link but i have confused with this deployment ?why some solution deployed globally and some solution deployed webapplication.
http://trentacular.com/2009/06/sharepoint-differences-between-global-and-web-application-targeted-solution-deployment/

Comment: @kavitha does above link provide you needful explanation?

Answer (score 0):

> SharePoint server 2013 solutions,some solutions are deployed in
> Globally and some solutions are deployed in web application.
>
> why this happening

This depends upon the scope of a feature, that you would define in `manifest.xml` file.

> what is the difference between globally
> deployed and web application deployed?

Copying a part of an answer from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1d336399-be16-47b1-8507-9e81ef0f4765/event-receiver-scope-given-as-web-but-while-deploying-no-url-choice-column-available-from-central?forum=sharepointadminlegacy):

> - If in the solution manifest, the assembly's attribute DeployementTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache", SharePoint will not ask you
>   for the web application.
> - If the attribute DeployementTarget="WebApplication", SharePoint will ask you for the web application to which the solution will be
>   deployed.
> - If the attribute DeployementTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" and SafeControls are needed for the assembly, especially for web parts,
>   SharePoint will ask for the we application, because the safe controls
>   are added to the web.config of the web application.

The end result would be, if a solution is deployed to webApplication1 and webApplication2, but not on webApplication3, you can use the features only on site collections under webApplication1 and webApplication2, but not for those under webApplication3. Instead, a globally deployed solution, will be available under all site collections - webApplication1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that if you deploy with a webapplication scope, not globally:

- your dlls will not be deployed to the GAC but in the bin folder in the main directory (by default in the wwwroot/inetpub) of the web application you chose.
- your feature(s) will not be installed in all web applications existing in your farm. The same goes for web.config modifications.
  Imagine you programmed a site-scoped feature in your wsp, you will only find this feature in the web application you chose.
- Sharepoint will not restart all the application pools in which all your web applications are executed, only the web application you targeted. Something very useful if you don't want to restart everything in your farm.